# Override a global variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, overriding

I am newbie in javascript development. For my project, I am using fullcalendar package (source: fullcalendar.io) in order to display my events on a calendar by subscribing to my ical feed (ics file), so that leads me to use iCalendar package (source: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/icalendar). And for some reasons I am not able to access my event's description. (I only have access to the title, startDate and endDate).

source code:

```
var FullCalendarICalendar = (function (exports, common, ICAL) {
    'use strict';

 ...
  function buildSingleEvent(iCalEvent) {
    return {
        title: iCalEvent.summary,
        start: iCalEvent.startDate.toString(),
        end: (iCalEvent.endDate ? iCalEvent.endDate.toString() : null),
    };
}
var plugin = common.createPlugin({
    eventSourceDefs: [eventSourceDef],
});

common.globalPlugins.push(plugin);

exports.default = plugin;

Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });

return exports;}({}, FullCalendar, ICAL));
```

By reviewing the source file main.global.js, I noticed that the variable FullCalendarICalendar is defined globally and I would like to override the function **buildSingleEvent** in order to add an extra field to store my event's description. But I have no idea how to do it, the structure is quit particular, it's a function defined in a global variable.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: this is a variant of the module pattern. the scope inside of the global function is private and can't be manipulated externally. as such, `buildSingleEvent` is not able to be overridden in 3rd party code. However, you could take a copy of the plugin and then modify the code directly. there is nothing stopping you from doing that, or even submitting a PR to the project to add description.

Comment: I have tried to fork the project and modify the package source code written in typescript. But I am not able to generate the same code structure as you can see. And that makes me crazy, I spent to much time on it. I would like to modify the source code properly and not the javascript file.

Comment: project github: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar
I managed to generate a main.js by following the instruction of CONTRIBUTING.md from the typescript code but it is unusable.

Comment: did you use `npm run build` or did you just try compiling with tsc?"

Comment: I have created a new project (following this: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/06/writing-a-node-module-in-typescript.html) and tried npm run build but the result is the same, the js code structure doesn't match the main.global.js file. I do not know how the author generates his main.global.js file

Comment: @r3wt, I have a new clue for this issue, I managed to generate the main.global.js file from the source project (github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar). But the problem is I have to build all the packages and not only those I would like to build. Do you have any idea achieving this ? It has to do with yarn.